# Native Storage Error, does not display the following screen

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to implement a login.

Which has 2 options to register one with your data that are in FB or the other put them manually.

In the first form you connect with fb and he brings your names and your mail, then sends you to the next window where you have to put your phone number

In the second option of resgitro you give where it says Register Now where it takes you to the same page that takes you from above only this time with empty fields.

My error arises when I give the second option and I get the following error and does not display the screen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

It tells me that it is empty Then my doubt is the following as I make it that when it arrives empty it shows the normal screen

> This is the code of my login with facebook:

```
loginWithFB() {
    let nav = this.navCtrl;
    let env = this;
    this.facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      this.facebook.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', [])
        .then(function (user) {
          env.nativeStorage.setItem('user',
            {
              name: user.name,
              email: user.email
            })
            .then(function () {
              nav.push(RegistroNPage);
              //console.log(user);
            }, function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
        })
    });
  }
```

> Maybe it's a mistake to be in this class:

```
ionViewCanEnter() {
        console.log('Ya llegue');
        let env = this;
        return this.nativeStorage.getItem('user')
            .then(function (data) {
                env.user = {
                    name: data.name,
                    email: data.email
                };
                console.log(env.user);
                env.userReady = true;
                return true;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            });
    }
```

And this is my html from my registration page where the 2 buttons arrive:

```
<ion-content padding class="body" align="center">
    <img src="assets/logito.png">
    <br>
    <br>

    <ion-list *ngIf="userReady">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input clearInput type="number" placeholder="Teléfono">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="dark" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='checkmark-circle-outline'></ion-icon>
        registar
      </button>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage#errors) this is the expected exception when you're trying to retrieve something from storage that doesn't exist (that key is not found). Which sounds right in this scenario, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @MattM How do i do an if in these cases

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. When should this key "user" actually exist in your nativeStorage service?

Comment: Can you post the code that is associated to the registration? After successful registration, you should store the user data like this: this.nativeStorage.setItem('user', user).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**fat arrow functions**](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) as shown below.

```
ionViewCanEnter() {
         let env = this;
        return this.nativeStorage.getItem('user')
            .then((data) => {
                env.user = {
                    name: data.name,
                    email: data.email
                };
                console.log(env.user);
                env.userReady = true;
                return true;
            }, (error)=> {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for my English, the error that presents esque does not happen to the next page, that class tells me that this vacion entocnes my question is how do I do an if so that when this vacion in the ngModel put me ""